# Using read.fwf() with HTTPS

Tags: r

I'm trying to read the fixed-width file directly from the server, without downloading and writing a file and parsing it.  If I do something like

```
> read.fwf(url("http://..."),columns)
```

then I get the response I want.  However, with an HTTPS server I get this response.

```
> read.fwf(url("https://..."),columns)
Error in url("https://...") : 
  https:// URLs are not supported
```

With other formats, I've been able to use something like method="curl", but this doesn't seem to work with read.fwf().

Another approach I've tried was to download the file into memory using getURL() then parse it, which works for me with CSV files using read.csv(text=data), but read.fwf() doesn't seem to support this method.

Comment: The base `read.fwf` actually opens a file, and writes a new copy as a delimited file, and then reads that translated version. It's always going to write to local disc. Try `read_fwf()` from the new [readr](https://github.com/hadley/readr) package.

Comment: So I'm really not saving anything compared to doing a straight download on the file then reading it back into memory?

Comment: Now with the standard read.fwf. But read_fwf is probably a lot better. Use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [curl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) package:

> The curl() function provides a drop-in replacement for base url() with better performance and support for http 2.0, ssl (https://, ftps://), gzip, deflate and other libcurl goodies.

Try:

```
library(curl)
read.fwf(curl("https://..."),columns)
```